# Keep menu up after clicking in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython to write an app.  I have a menu that pops up.  I would like to know how to keep it on the screen after the user clicks an item on the menu.  I only want it to go away after the click off it or if I tell it to in the programming.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I am using RHEL 6 and wxPython 3.01.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the regular `wx.PopupMenu` will work that way. However if you look at the wxPython demo, you will see a neat widget called `wx.PopupWindow` that claims it can be used as a menu and it appears to work the way you want. The `wx.PopupTransientWindow` might also work.